# Barba.js Reinitalise page after transition in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, barbajs

I have a common problem with barba.js in wordpress. I am work through this: https://codepen.io/dan-oc/pen/gvLaGB and this https://barbajs.org/demo/nextprev/index.html example. Problem is that, after page transition page design is distroyed, even previous page also. I know there are a lot of topics in stackoverflow and other forums about this problem and there are some answers. I tried to benefit from them, the result always the same. i dont know what is problem. First i thougt that, may be, script and style files in the footer and head have not been load after transition but, i saw that had been loaded after page transition. then what is the problem if everything loaded after transition.  can anyone help me please. My javascript knowledge is weak and i am new in ajax technology. Thanks for your attention.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var lastElementClicked;
    Barba.Pjax.init();
    Barba.Prefetch.init();
Barba.Dispatcher.on('linkClicked', function(el) {
    lastElementClicked = el;
  });
  
   var Body = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: '#barba-wrapper',
      sync: true,
        onEnter() {},
        onEnterCompleted() {},
        onLeave() {},
        onLeaveCompleted() {}
    });

    Body.init();
    
    var Homepage = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: 'homep',
      sync: true,
        onEnter() {},
        onEnterCompleted() {},
        onLeave() {},
        onLeaveCompleted() {}
    });

    Homepage.init();

    var About = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: 'aboutp',
      sync: true,
        onEnter() {},
        onEnterCompleted() {},
        onLeave() {},
        onLeaveCompleted() {}
    });

    About.init();
    
    var Newspress = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: 'newsp',
      sync: true,
        onEnter() {},
        onEnterCompleted() {},
        onLeave() {},
        onLeaveCompleted() {}
    });

    Newspress.init();
    
    var Tedbirler = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: 'tedbirlerp',
      sync: true,
        onEnter() {},
        onEnterCompleted() {},
        onLeave() {},
        onLeaveCompleted() {}
    });

    Tedbirler.init();

    var pageTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
        start: function() {
            this.newContainerLoading.then(
                val => this.fadeInNewcontent(this.newContainer, this.oldContainer)
            );
        },
        transitionFinished(newContainer, oldContainer) {
            newContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            this.done();
        },
        fadeInNewcontent: function(newContainer, oldContainer) {
            newContainer.classList.add('new');

            var _this = this;

            const transition = this.oldContainer.animate([
                { opacity: 1 }, 
                { opacity: 0 }
            ], {duration: 1500});

            transition.onfinish = function() {
                _this.transitionFinished(newContainer, oldContainer);
            };
        }
    });

    Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
        return pageTransition;
    }

    Barba.Pjax.start();

}, false);
```

Comment: Better to use barba.js V2 - https://barba.js.org

Comment: this problem fixed there?